# xCode EXC_Arithmetic(code=EXC_1386_DIV,subcode=0x0) debug

Tags: xcode, debugging

Hi i've this debug "error" when my action is starting:

```
EXC_Arithmetic(code=EXC_1386_DIV,subcode=0x0)
```

My code is following:

```
 // checking if an ad may be shown due to ads frequency for this ad network and this location
            if (placementCountChartboostGameOver % ADS_FREQUENCY_CHARTBOOST_GAME_OVER == 0) {
                mayShowChartboostAdAtLocation = YES;

                if (cKLogEnabled) {
                    CKLog(@"App may show Chartboost Ad at Game Over because placement count is %li and ads frequency at this location is %li.", (long)placementCountChartboostGameOver, (long)ADS_FREQUENCY_CHARTBOOST_GAME_OVER);
                }

            }
```

My debug "error" is starting at: `placementCountChartboostGameOver % ADS_FREQUENCY_CHARTBOOST_GAME_OVER == 0`

Comment: Is `ADS_FREQUENCY_CHARTBOOST_GAME_OVER` equal to zero?

Comment: Nope it's equal to 1.

Comment: Why are you doing mod 1? mod 1 is always zero.

Comment: Are you sure `ADS_FREQUENCY_CHARTBOOST_GAME_OVER` is an integer?